# Why can't install npm to create package.json on AWS EC2?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2

I'm trying use EC2 to execute command `npm install` will get bellow error.
(Node.js had already install)

Dose anybody know why?

Is that the reason that I execute this command `chmod 400` before login EC2 by ssh?

`chmod 400` seems only could read, isn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install` only works if there is an existing package.json file. Your `ls` command shows that the directory is empty.

If you want to create your initial package.json file, you want to use the command `npm init` and answer the questions.